# How can I get subtitles for chapter titles to appear in the ToC, but not in the page headers with arsclassica?

Tags: table-of-contents

I only need the subtitles to appear in the ToC because the titles are too long.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{classicthesis,arsclassica}

\newcommand*{\Chapter}[2]{%
    \chapter[#1: \textit{#2}]{#1}%
    \begingroup
    \raggedright\Large\itshape
    #2\par
    \endgroup
    \nobreak\vspace{\glueexpr \bigskipamount*3 \relax}%
    % Adjust this factor as needed ..........^
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\Chapter{Il titolo}{E il sottotitolo}

Testo.

\end{document}
```

Comment: if i understand your question correctly, after `\chapter`, you should set `\markboth{#1}{#1}` to set up the running heads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only imagine that you want this, though in this case the title seems to be quite short.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\newcommand*{\Chapter}[2]{%
\chapter[\textit{#2}]{#1}%
\begingroup
\raggedright\Large\itshape
#2\par
\endgroup
\nobreak\vspace{\glueexpr \bigskipamount*3 \relax}%
    % Adjust this factor as needed ..........^
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\Chapter{Il titolo}{E il sottotitolo}

Testo.

\end{document}
```

Comment: That was my idea too, but I think, it's about the page headers, i.e. with `\markboth` ... etc

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ^^^^^^  ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B: Unclear X - Y question, but I don't care any longer about such stuff